# Jquery Mobile page Anchor on page working inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple page with two sections identified with a , and linked using a Jquery Mobile formatted link on the same page (Refresh Rate), and it doesn't seem to work consistently.

Although I am using this in a PhoneGap application, the same problem happens when I try to load the page locally in Chrome.

```
<head>
    <title>TPS/TFS CAD Page</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tfscad.mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/js.cookie.js"></script> 
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function save_val(va) {
        localStorage.setItem('refreshrate', va );
       var refreshrate=localStorage.getItem('refreshrate');

   alert('The refreshrate is set to ' + refreshrate);     
      }


</script>   


</head>


<body>

<div id="options" data-role="page">

<!-- Start of first page -->

    <div data-role="header">
<a href="" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext">Back</a>  

        <h1>Options</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="alertslist.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-right ui-state-disabled">Alerts</a>
<a href="filterslist.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-right ui-state-disabled">Filters</a>
<a href="#refopt" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-right" >Refresh Rate</a>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="refopt">

    <div data-role="header">
<a href="" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext">Back</a>  
        <h1>Refresh Rate</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right">
                <legend>The frequency that the application refreshes the dispatched events. 
                    Increasing this may reduce data usage, but will slow down how quickly you are notified of a new event</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="refreshtime" id="10" value="10000" checked="checked" onclick="save_val('10000')">
                <label for="10">10 Seconds (Default)</label>
                <input type="radio" name="refreshtime" id="20" value="20000" onclick="save_val('20000')">
                <label for="20">20 Seconds</label>
                <input type="radio" name="refreshtime" id="30" value="30000" onclick="save_val('30000')">
                <label for="30">30 Seconds</label>
                <input type="radio" name="refreshtime" id="60" value="60000" onclick="save_val('60000')">
                <label for="60">1 Minute</label>
                <input type="radio" name="refreshtime" id="120" value="120000" onclick="save_val('120000')">
                <label for="120">2 Minutes</label>
                </fieldset>
</div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">

        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>

<!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is happening when it doesn't work?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I have taken a look in the console and there are no errors. The only time I seem to be able to get it to work is if I go to one of the above links (currently disabled) and go back to the page. It will then navigate to the anchor as expected.